# получить текст Textview в recyclerView item с помощью onClick в Kotlin

Tags: recyclerview, kotlin, onclicklistener, setonclicklistener

у меня есть Main3Activity и UsersAdapter

в UsersAdapter у меня есть clickListener

Click listener в UsersAdapter:

```
open class RecyclerItemClickListener(recyclerView: RecyclerView, private val mListener: OnItemClickListener?) : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private var mGestureDetector: GestureDetector = GestureDetector(recyclerView.context, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {}
    })

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(view: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView))
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(view: RecyclerView, motionEvent: MotionEvent) {

    }
    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
}
```

в Main3Activity он вызывается следующим образом:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        UsersAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(recyclerView,
            object : UsersAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@Main3Activity, "${firstName?.text}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                }
            })
    )
```

Мне нужно, что при нажатии на firstName появлялся Toast с текстом firstName в item-e, например при нажатии на C++ появляется тост с c++, а при нажатии на HTML появляется тост HTML, но у меня  Toast не появляется.
[image: recyclerView]
Как я могу это сделать?
ОООЧЕНЬ нужна Ваша помощь. Заранее спасибо

Comment: ну так вызовите у toast метод show()

Comment: Блин, протупил, но проблема немножко не в этом: тост показывает только текст первого объекта, даже когда нажимаю HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, я понял, нужно было поменять

```
Toast.makeText(this@Main3Activity, "${firstName?.text}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

на

```
Toast.makeText(this@Main3Activity, "${yourRecyclerArray[position]}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```